# Phoenix elixir wont install dependency (comeonin)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a working phoenix app and I am trying to install a new dependency called **comeonin**

I added the dependency inside mix.exs file like this at the end of the applications list.

```
  def application do
    [mod: {Rumbl, []},
     applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_pubsub, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
                    :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex, :comeonin]]
  end
```

But when I run `mix deps.get` it seems to ignore that dependency and wont install it:

```
$ mix deps.get
Running dependency resolution...
Dependency resolution completed:
  connection 1.0.4
  cowboy 1.1.2
  cowlib 1.0.2
  db_connection 1.1.2
  decimal 1.4.0
  ecto 2.1.6
  file_system 0.1.5
  gettext 0.13.1
  mime 1.1.0
  phoenix 1.2.5
  phoenix_ecto 3.2.3
  phoenix_html 2.10.3
  phoenix_live_reload 1.1.0
  phoenix_pubsub 1.0.2
  plug 1.3.5
  poison 2.2.0
  poolboy 1.5.1
  postgrex 0.13.3
  ranch 1.3.2
All dependencies up to date
```

And it doesnt appear neither in the deps/ folder

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you added it to the `defp deps do` block? should be somewhere below where `def application do` is defined.

Comment: I was missing that, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, inside the `mix.exs` file be sure that the dependency is defined in the `defp deps` block as well.